# why can't i change anything related to brightness on my system?

Tags: release-hera, brightness

So i'm on elementary OS 5.1.7 Hera, and i had some trouble with installing it, so in the end i have to go through recovery boot every time for it to boot - i'm mentioning that because maybe that's the cause of the problem. But basically i can't get night light, flux, redshift to work, and i can't control the brightness. I can't even control the brightness through teriminal, through various solutions i found online. anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

For

> go through recovery boot every time for it to boot

Just make sure you set the correct boot sequence in bios.

And for

> night light, flux, redshift

Are you using desktop or laptop? Is it support brightness control or night light in Windows 10? If windows doesn't work that mean your hardware doesn't have the ability to control brightness.

If it works in Windows 10, check your kernel version using `uname -r` in terminal. Are you using 4.15?

I'm using kernel version 5.4 and so far so good here.

Comment: Hey, yeah,  i had win10 before and i could normally control brightness and f.lux functioned (normally). I'm on the 5.10.13 version on a laptop